# Undefined control sequence with \green and \red

Tags: color

The following is table.tex:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tabular}{ l | r }
  Problem & Expansions \\
   \hline
    {\green Unit} Grid & \green 382,536 \\
    {\red Life} Grid & \red 994,437 \\
    \hline
    {\green Unit} Pancake & \green 69 \\
    {\red Sum} Pancake & \red 3,711 \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

When I do:

```
latex table
```

I get this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.14       {\green
                   Unit} Grid & \green 382,536 \
```

I get similar errors for the other uses of `\red` and `\green`.  Doing `\usepackage{color}` with `\red` and `\green` works with other documents, I don't understand why it doesn't work in this context.

Comment: You need to use `\color{green}` or `\textcolor{green}{<green text>}`.

Answer (score 5):

```
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tabular}{ l | r }
    Problem & Expansions \\
    \hline
    {\color{green} Unit} Grid & {\color{green} 382,536} \\
    {\color{red} Life} Grid & {\color{red} 994,437} \\
    \hline
    {\color{green} Unit} Pancake & {\color{green} 69} \\
    {\color{red} Sum} Pancake & {\color{red} 3,711} \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This how you need to define the color changes with the `color` package.  Here is a link to the wiki reference https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors

[image]

Per egreg's suggestions,

```
\begin{document}
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \begin{tabular}{ l | r }
    Problem & Expansions \\
    \hline
    \textcolor{green}{Unit} Grid & \textcolor{green}{382,536} \\
    \textcolor{red}{Life} Grid & \textcolor{red}{994,437} \\
    \hline
    \textcolor{green}{Unit} Pancake & \textcolor{green}{69} \\
    \textcolor{red}{Sum} Pancake & \textcolor{red}{3,711} \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also `\textcolor{green}{Unit}`, which seems more apt for this case, requiring no outer braces.

Comment: Thank you for the answer to how to get it to work correctly.  I think the reason it worked elsewhere is it was within a powerdot presentation, which apparently allows \green and \red.